# Laravel find an item contains specific string value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, backend

One field on a table contains an object that has the information of a game (both team names, both team scores etc.). My question is how can I check if an item contains specific **competitorId** value?

**Table Field Value**

```
[{
    "competitorType": "TEAM",
    "competitorName": "Team A",
    "competitorId": 40000,
    "linkDetailCompetitor": "\/v1\/basketball\/teams\/40000",
    "scoreString": "85",
    "scoreSecondaryString": "",
    "completionStatus": "COMPLETE",
    "resultPlacing": 0,
    "isDrawn": 0,
    "isHomeCompetitor": 0,
    "teamId": 40000,
    "teamName": "Team A",
    "teamNameInternational": "",
    "teamNickname": "A",
    "teamNicknameInternational": "",
    "teamCode": "TA",
    "teamCodeInternational": "",
    "website": "",
    "internationalReference": "",
    "externalId": "71",
    "clubId": 1067,
    "clubName": "Team A",
    "clubNameInternational": "",
}, {
    "competitorType": "TEAM",
    "competitorName": "Team B",
    "competitorId": 40001,
    "linkDetailCompetitor": "\/v1\/basketball\/teams\/40001",
    "scoreString": "89",
    "scoreSecondaryString": "",
    "completionStatus": "COMPLETE",
    "resultPlacing": 1,
    "isDrawn": 0,
    "isHomeCompetitor": 1,
    "teamId": 40001,
    "teamName": "Team B",
    "teamNameInternational": "",
    "teamNickname": "B",
    "teamNicknameInternational": "",
    "teamCode": "TB",
    "teamCodeInternational": "",
    "website": "",
    "internationalReference": "",
    "externalId": "72",
    "clubId": 1095,
    "clubName": "Team B",
    "clubNameInternational": "",
}]
```

**Model Method**

```
public static function getTeamWinLossRecord($competitionId, $teamId) {
    $data = self::select('competitors')
            ->where('competitionId', $competitionId)
            ->get()
            ->map(function($item, $teamId){
                return $item->competitors;
            });
    dd($data);
}
```

**Returned Data**

```
Collection {#396 ▼
  #items: array:120 [▼
    0 => "[{"competitorType":"TEAM","competitorName":"Team A","competitorId":40000,"linkDetailCompetitor":"\/v1\/basketball\/teams\/40000","scoreString":"95","score ▶"
    1 => "[{"competitorType":"TEAM","competitorName":"Team C","competitorId":40001,"linkDetailCompetitor":"\/v1\/basketball\/teams\/40001","scoreString":"84", ▶"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flatten` to make all objects in same level, then filter it using `filter` or `whereIn`.

```
$newData = $data->flatten()->filter(function($val) {
    return $val->competitorId === "someIdid"
)}
```

More details can check on [laravel filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter) and [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-wherein)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a php function `in_array()` for search a specific string value

Font: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Going off your answer, the Collection class has a contains method that does essentially the same thing.